# Network connection issues in Windows 10

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, network-shares

I am trying to connect a certain laptop to a network but, I get an error.

Here is the code:

```
netsh wlan set profileparameter name='ssid' encryption=tkip authentication=wpa authmode=useronly
```

And here comes the error:

> Function wpgenerateprofilexml returns error 1206:
>   The network connection profile is corrupted.

This only happens on windows 10.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try it in the following manner

First time

> netsh wlan set profileparameter name='ssid' encryption=tkip authentication=wpa2 authmode=useronly

Second time

> netsh wlan set profileparameter name='ssid' encryption=tkip authentication=wpa authmode=useronly

We can and do twice.

Comment: When I try that command I got "Profile parameter "'ssid'" is not found on any available network"  Put in the actual SSID and the same message (except of course the part in quotes).  Then dismissed the command Window so the guy could go work on a different network.  But (new idea) opened another DOS window and did it without the '.  This time, the entire command line was displayed and it said it is not a recognized command.  Put the ' back in and it still did the second message.